# how to show data through input tag

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am working on a Django project .In front-end I want to add user data through input tags but I do not know how to save data through input tags
**My models.py file is:**:

```html
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    full_name       = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    sur_name        = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email           = models.EmailField(max_length=255 ,unique=True)
    choose_subject  = models.CharField(choices=SUBJECT_CHOICES , max_length=100)
    staff           = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin           = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    time_stamp      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    father_name     = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    father_sur_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mobile_phone_number    = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    father_email    = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    fiscal_code     = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address         = models.CharField(max_length=200 )
```

**A part of my register.html file is:**

```html
  <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="title">Registration Form</h2>
                    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="row row-space">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label class="label">Full name</label>
                                    <input class="input--style-4" type="text" name="first_name"{{form.full_name}}>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label class="label">Sur name</label>
                                    <input class="input--style-4" type="text" name="last_name"{{form.sur_name}}>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I just want the Django model field to be working in input tags

Comment: You can use the `value` attribute to set and extract data from input tag.

Comment: can you please wrote the syntax

Comment: Try setting: `<input class="input--style-4" type="text" name="first_name" value="{{form.full_name}}">` to set the value of the input.

Comment: sir this is still not working I edit my question and add my model also . kindly look at that

Comment: refer  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You must create in the views.py file a method in which the templates and the logic of it, an example can be the following
views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        var1 = request.POST.get('var1')
        var2 = request.POST.get('var2')
        var3 = request.POST.get('var3')

        #Save to the database here

        return render_to_response(
            'home.html',
            {'message': 'Update Success', }
        )
    else:
    #elif request.method == "GET":
        obj = table.objects.all()
        if obj:
            ctx['data'] = obj

        return render(request, template_name, ctx)
```

and in your template add a form tag

```
<form method="POST">
    { % csrf_token % }
    <div class="row row-space">
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="label">Full name</label>
                <input class="input--style-4" type="text" value={{data.full_name}}>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="label">Sur name</label>
                <input class="input--style-4" type="text" value={{data.sur_name}}>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="OK">

</form>
```

refer this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms)

Comment: I did make the view for this. And it is getting all the data when i say {{form}} but i want to customize the form by using css and javascript with like i use in this template but with js and css customized i can not say {{form.surname}} etc . How to make my form work

Comment: tell me if I understood it right, you want to show some default value in the input field.
and you want to style the form using CSS and js

Comment: Yes this is what i want

Comment: I want to customize the form usingcss and javascript

Comment: I have made changes in the answer. When register function is called for the through HTML, the get method is called and the code in else part runs(or ```request.method == "GET"```) the data through the dictionary is sent to the template and then you can display the data in the template